# Remove an entry from a List<int[]> based on the value of of a specific index

Tags: java, java-8, int, remove-if

I have a list of `ints` like the following one:

```
1318 1065 0
1392 1109 0
1522 1114 2
1764 1134 0
1643 1172 0
1611 1141 0
1608 1142 4
1689 1180 0
1546 1144 0
1811 1121 1
1682 1144 0
1687 1203 0
1751 1138 0
1702 1227 0
```

My goal is to **keep** only entries where the third element is a 0.

I've tried a few things like:

```
for( int i=0; i<data_fin.size();i++) {
    data_fin.removeIf(s -> !((data_fin.get(i)[2]) == 0));
}
```

I get the error 'Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final'.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm quite new to Java and I'm probably using `removeif` wrong, so I would appreciate the help!

Comment: is it 2d array integers or what?

Comment: Why are you using `removeIf` in a loop here anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My goal is to `keep` only entries where the third element is a 0

You don't need a loop in this, all you need is :

```
data_fin.removeIf(a -> a[2] != 0);
```

Comment: A lot easier than I thought. Still not very familiar with Java. Thanks a lot!!